# WalletPasses - Push Updates

Tags: push-notification, android-pay, wallet, passkit

I have integrated both Apple and Google passes into my webapp, both work, both receive push updates.

But the Apple implementation (user experience) is much nicer than the Google one, and the development and implementation of passes a lot simpler than Google's.

I've been looking at PKPass applications for Android to use a common look and feel of pass across all users, and the WalletPasses one works super well. They claim to support Push updates ... but I'm having a hard time getting them to actually work.

Passes register with my server, they download updates manually on swipe down, they unregister from the server. I send a push notification to the WalletPasses server and get a 200 response, but this never seems to connect to the app on the device to download an update to the pass.

Has anyone succeeded in making it work, or are they aware of any other provider that supports PKPass push notifications (not looking for a free service).

Mat

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this app - `PassWallet` - [PassWallet Github](https://github.com/Kwiket/passwallet). Seems WalletPasses hasn't migrated to FCM from GCM.

Comment: Sorry delayed response, thank you! PassWallet push updates do work, just seems a small issue within the app about displaying the update if you aren't 'active' in the app. E-mailing developer.

I'm surprised more people don't raise this as an issue because Google Pay Passes are so terrible!